# Decoding a url in Python

Tags: python, url, decode

Can somebody explain how to decode [this](http://members.coderdojosv.org/connect?arc=jTrZ5%2A6%287&cdb=X%5Byew%27%3C%26%3E%28) in Python?

I already tried:

```
>>> import urllib

>>> some_string='arc=jTrZ5%2A6%287&cdb=X%5Byew%27%3C%26%3E%28'
>>> urllib.parse.unquote(urllib.parse.unquote(some_string))
```

and I got this:

```
arc=jTrZ5*6(7&cdb=X[yew'<&>(
```

Comment: Why do you unquote twice?

Comment: this does not tell us anything...

Comment: @Seekheart -What do you mean?

Comment: @zondo - I found it on a different Stack Overflow place.

Comment: Well, as DavidHisting mentioned, it is useless.  That is like translating German into English and then translating *that* into English.  The second translation is useless because it's already in the right language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description for unquote is "Replace %xx escapes by their single-character equivalent" (https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html). You can check the results using this site: http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php.  Using the first sequence, %2A you can see that it resolves to '*'.  The last enclosing call to 'unquote' essentially does nothing except echo the previous result.

Comment: Okay, I realized that this is not UTF-8 encryption. Sigh. I'll just accept the solution of @David Histing.